# Scroll-stopping script not working with my responsive site

Tags: jquery, mousewheel

I couldn't find the answer to this question, but let me know if anyone finds a similar discussion.

So my problem is that I have the mousewheel script: https://raw.github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/master/jquery.mousewheel.js

With this jQuery script:

```
$(function() {

  var toolbox = $('#projects'),
      height = toolbox.height(),
      scrollHeight = toolbox.get(0).scrollHeight;

  toolbox.bind('mousewheel', function(e, d) {
    if((this.scrollTop === (scrollHeight - height) && d < 0) || (this.scrollTop === 0 && d > 0)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });

});
```

To stop the left panel from scrolling the whole page, like this: http://probando.rayniel.com, however, when you change the responsive stage, the website completely ignores all the scripts and only works at the responsive stage you started at. And only that stage, unless you refresh.

I tried looking for other solutions but I like this script because it retains the natural smooth scrolling.

Also, I created a class called "mousescroll" that only shows scrollbars when you hover on the scrollable area.

I hope I was clear,
I appreciate any help, thank you in advance!

Comment: I cant see the problem in Safari 6.0.2

Comment: I have Safari 6.0.2 as well. You tried resizing your browser window and then scrolling the left panel?